# The limit of a fraction

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals, fractions, limits-without-lhopital

What is the value of
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x^4-1}}{2x^2+3x-1}$$
I tried to factorise the denominator or the numerator but it takes me nowhere. My teacher said it equals to $\frac{1}{2}$. But I don't get it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Factor $x^4$ from the numerator and bring it out of the sqr, then simplify a bit :-)

Comment: Use the Laurent Series to represent the series expansion at $x = \infty$: $$\frac{1}{2} - \frac{3}{4x} + \frac{11}{8x^2} - \frac{39}{16x^3} + \frac{131}{32x^4} + \mathcal{O}\bigg(\frac{1}{x^5}\bigg)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just dividing the numerator and denominator by $x^2$ gives $\frac{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^4}}}{2-\frac{3}{x}-\frac{1}{x^2}}$. Now taking limit $x \rightarrow \infty $ gives the answer $\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Factor out and simplify the highest power of $x$ in the denominator and in the numerator:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x^4-1}}{2x^2+3x-1} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^2\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^4}}}{x^2\left(2+\frac{3}{x}-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^4}}}{2+\frac{3}{x}-\frac{1}{x^2}}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x^4-1}}{2x^2+3x-1}=\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^4}}}{2+\frac{3}{x}-\frac{1}{x^2}}=\frac{1}{2}$$
Also
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x^4-1}}{2x^2+3x-1}=\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}\frac{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^4}}}{2+\frac{3}{x}-\frac{1}{x^2}}=\frac{1}{2}$$
Thus, indeed, the answer is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\sqrt{x^4-1}}{2x^2+3x-1}=
\frac{x^2\sqrt{1-1/x^4}}{x^2(2+3/x-1/x^2)}=
\frac{\sqrt{1-1/x^4}}{2+3/x-1/x^2}$$